# Why isn't a Dart considered a "Light" weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

It weighs the least amount on the entire weapons list.  Even a hand crossbow is considered a "Light" weapon.

Comment: Related: [Can You Two-Weapon Fight With a Dart?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77323/can-you-two-weapon-fight-with-a-dart)

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation from a dev, or something else?

Comment: Explanation from a dev would be great, but Im just looking to understand why they didnt choose to make a dart a "Light" weapon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Being light doesn't have anything to do with weight. The definition of a Light weapon is as follows:

> ***Light.***
>   A
>   light
>   weapon
>   is
>   small
>   and
>   easy
>   to
>   handle,
>   making
>   it
>   ideal
>   for
>   use
>   when
>   fighting
>   with
>   two
>   weapons.

Darts are small, obviously. So if a dart isn't a light weapon, it's because it isn't easy to handle, and therefore, not ideal for two-weapon fighting.

Note that while he doesn't say why, [Crawford confirmed that darts are not meant to be light](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/04/15/has-the-dart-been-made-a-light-weapon-via-erratasage-advice/). [Twice](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/10/01/can-you-throw-darts-with-each-hand-in-the-same-round/).

Comment: Then why add Hand Crossbows to the "Light" list? It too cannot be used in TWF.  Why, as a rogue, does it make sense to use slight of hand to hide a "Light" Hand crossbow but not a dart?

Comment: @AlSun Well, [Mearls says](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/09/01/light-weapons-property/) it's for use in DM rulings. But that's a different question ([this one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44773/15469)), and it's not really a sensible way to approach this one - "This extremely unusual weapon is light, why isn't this other weapon?" Hand crossbows are definitely the exception not the rule.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  Seeing as there are no other answers I'll accept this one - Darts are small but not easy to handle thus not really a light weapon.  Im guessing the Dev wanted to make sure that darts would never be used for TWF.  Thanks again.