# RAW, Can two weapon fighting be used with nets?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, two-weapon-fighting

Two weapon fighting has a clause that seems to imply the weapon need not be a melee weapon, if it has the thrown property.

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative. **If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon, instead of making a melee attack with it.**

**Can you two weapon fight with non melee thrown weapons, such as a net?**

Assume that that the attacker has the dual wielder feat.

Comment: Related: [What function does the “light” weapon property serve on the hand crossbow?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44773/33707)

Comment: thanks @NautArch; it was early and on mobile. fixed

Answer (score 11):

#### No

The first part describes the requirements for two-weapon fighting, and it clearly says you need to use light **melee** weapons.

The throwing part is merely to clarify that you can throw your melee weapon as part of two-weapon fighting. It's doesn't change the conditions.

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand.