# Does the light crossbow have the "light" property?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

This question may seem strange or self-explanatory, but I noticed that the [light crossbow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/crossbow-light), despite its name, doesn't have the "light" property listed in its "properties" section. Can it be inferred, from the light crossbow's name, that it has the “light” property?

The reason I ask this is because I'm investigating creating a feat similar to Great Weapon Master that utilizes the “light” property, and I want to know if there are any weapons that would qualify which are not one-handed weapons.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @Groody Just a gentle request: Only adding a DDB link adds very little of value, doubly so if it's not to material that's obscure or otherwise ambiguous. It would be better to do this when also making other edits so you aren't filling the homepage with trivial edits.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Thanks, will do so in future, and hold my activities for now.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### No

It is not a light weapon. If it was, it would have the Light property.

The name light is a) legacy (the crossbow, light has been in D&D since at least AD&D) and b) relative to the other models of crossbow. The name does not grant weapon properties.

Comment: Is the Light spell a light weapon?  Enquiring minds and all.

Comment: @TigerGuy If you cast it on the crossbow, I'd call that a Light weapon.

Comment: @RutherRendommeleigh That'd be light*ed*, not light. If you set it on fire, it'd be both *a*light, and light*ed*, which also makes it a light... but it's still not Light, despite being an alighted light crossbow.  :)

Comment: @T.J.L. that's quite an *enlightened* comment

Comment: Do not operate while consuming lite beer.

Comment: If you made a illusory crossbow, is it made out of light and therefore a light weapon?

Comment: @yesennes only if you cast the light cantrip on it and set it on fire, in which case it would be an *alight lighted light crossbow made of light.*

Comment: This discussion is lit.

Comment: As a side note, the shadow blade created by the spell of the same name is a light weapon ^^

Comment: Here's a real life example- the [minigun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHgZh4GV9G0) isn't mini.

Answer (score 19):

#### The "Crossbow, light" has the properties "Ammunition (range 80/320), loading, two-handed"

From the [Simple Ranged Weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#SimpleRangedWeapons) table in chapter 5 of the PHB, we see that the light crossbow does not have the "light" property:

| Weapon Name | Cost | Damage | Weight | Properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Crossbow, light | 25 gp | 1d8 piercing | 5 lb. | Ammunition (range 80/320), loading, two-handed |

If the light crossbow had the "light" property, this is where we would see it listed, as the rules explain:

> The Weapons table shows the most common weapons used in the fantasy gaming worlds, their price and weight, the damage they deal when they hit, and *any special properties they possess*.

So no, it does not have the "light" property. The only ranged weapon listed with the "light" property is the hand crossbow, on the [Martial Ranged Weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#MartialRangedWeapons) table:

| Weapon Name | Cost | Damage | Weight | Properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Crossbow, hand | 75 gp | 1d6 piercing | 3 lb. | Ammunition (range 80/320), light, loading |

Comment: The light crossbow is the hand crossbow, not the light crossbow.  Got it.

Comment: @Yakk Unfortunately, you are correct.

Answer (score 12):

### No, and there would be no point if it had

Nothing in the properties for the light crossbow states that it has the light property. On top of that, from the rules on weapons:

> A light weapon is small and easy to handle, making it ideal for use when fighting with two weapons.

A light crossbow has the property: "two-handed". As such, you need both hands to wield one. The light property would be meaningless as it only relevant when dual wielding weapons.

Comment: Two-Weapon Fighting also requires *melee* weapons, so it'd be doubly useless

Comment: @Medix2 yet the Hand Crossbow has the light property

Comment: @RHS And we have [an entire question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44773) on whether that serves any purpose and [it does not](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/44776)"

Comment: @Medix2 which proves that it being pointless is irrelevant to the question whether it could have the property

Comment: @RHS We are clearly misunderstanding each other. I am simply saying that a ranged weapon has *no reason* to have the light property, as that answer shows. Thus, the light crossbow having the property would be double useless: not only is it two-handed but it is also ranged.